# unbind a service but not destroy it

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-service, bind

Here I want to use my service called deadreckoning service to update my UI, when this activity stops, i want keep the service still working, so i have not use unbind method, the problem is, every time I destroy the fragment with UI without unbind method, the Logcat give the error which is my memory is leak, actually i defined the stopService in other place, so how could i eliminate this error? do i need to put a pre-defined flag in bind method instead of 0? Folling is my bind code:

```
    if (DeadReckoningService.isDeadReckoningStart) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DeadReckoningService.class);
        getActivity().bindService(intent, connection, 0);
        serviceUpdateUI.post(runnable);
    }
```

Thanks for your answers, maybe I did not explain the question well.
Here is some add-on explaination on the environment:

Actually I first use startService in a broadcastReceiver to start.
Then use bindService in the a Activity(RunFragment) to communication with this background service and update UI.

When I close this runFragment, I do not want stop the service, I still want it to make some log in back ground. So I just want it stop the communication with runFragment, so I do not use unbindService(cause it will also stop the service). At this moment in logcat I get the error imforamtion which my memory is leaking. How to avoid this error information is I want to ask.

So When do I stop the service? When the user next time opened this runFragment again, when user press stop button, which call stopservice, the communication and UIupdate stuff are over.

Here are the error report in Logcat

```
 01-17 10:34:58.422: E/ActivityThread(21666): Activity study.runtracker.RunActivity has leaked ServiceConnection study.runtracker.RunFragment$2@425d6828 that was originally bound here
01-17 10:34:58.422: E/ActivityThread(21666): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity study.runtracker.RunActivity has leaked ServiceConnection study.runtracker.RunFragment$2@425d6828 that was originally bound here
01-17 10:34:58.422: E/ActivityThread(21666):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:979)
01-17 10:34:58.422: E/ActivityThread(21666):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:873)
01-17 10:34:58.422: E/ActivityThread(21666):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1561)
01-17 10:34:58.422: E/ActivityThread(21666):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1544)
01-17 10:34:58.422: E/ActivityThread(21666):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:517)
01-17 10:34:58.422: E/ActivityThread(21666):    at study.runtracker.RunFragment.onStart(RunFragment.java:74)
01-17 10:34:58.422: E/ActivityThread(21666):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1524)
01-17 10:34:58.422: E/ActivityThread(21666):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:957)
01-17 10:34:58.422: E/ActivityThread(21666):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
01-17 10:34:58.422: E/ActivityThread(21666):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
01-17 10:34:58.422: E/ActivityThread(21666):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:1889)
01-17 10:34:58.422: E/ActivityThread(21666):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:587)
01-17 10:34:58.422: E/ActivityThread(21666):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
01-17 10:34:58.422: E/ActivityThread(21666):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
01-17 10:34:58.422: E/ActivityThread(21666):    at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:5297)
01-17 10:34:58.422: E/ActivityThread(21666):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5302)
01-17 10:34:58.422: E/ActivityThread(21666):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
01-17 10:34:58.422: E/ActivityThread(21666):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
01-17 10:34:58.422: E/ActivityThread(21666):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
01-17 10:34:58.422: E/ActivityThread(21666):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-17 10:34:58.422: E/ActivityThread(21666):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-17 10:34:58.422: E/ActivityThread(21666):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-17 10:34:58.422: E/ActivityThread(21666):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 10:34:58.422: E/ActivityThread(21666):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-17 10:34:58.422: E/ActivityThread(21666):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-17 10:34:58.422: E/ActivityThread(21666):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-17 10:34:58.422: E/ActivityThread(21666):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Put complete code here, also check if logcat has any warning if yes put that here as well.

Answer (score 5):

use startService before binding

Answer (score 1):

It's actually possible to do both: bind to a Service and explicitly start and stop it. Binding to a service is particularly useful only if you need to share data from the Service to the Activity/other Context it is bound to. It sounds like for your needs, you want to use `startService()` and `stopService()` to control the lifecycle of your Service. If you still need to pass data back, then you can also `bindService()` after creating it with the `startService()` method.

[Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Answer (score 0):

instead of using a bound service why don't implement a start service?

[Check the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html), you'll find out that there's another way to do that.
The bound service, as the name suggests, lives till there is someone bounded to it.